# Unable to set default program for 1 file type

Tags: windows-7, file-association

I've exhausted everything I can think of to fix this.

Basically my indesign documents lost their file extension association. No other file extensions seem to be affected. Interestingly they do still have the indesign icon. Haven't done any adobe updates for some time and this was working just fine on this computer for at least a year or two. Just started happening last night.

When I try to use the typical open with, and select indesign manually, I am still unable to open with indesign. I can select the indesign application from Program Files, but the icon doesn't actually show up in the dialog box so I can't actually use it to open the file.

[image: Selecting indesign application]

Indesign still isn't an option after selecting it.

[image: Application still not at option]

I've tried other programs like notepad+ and they show up as an option, but when I try and use either version of indesign, neither will show up in the open with options.

I have double checked the programs both work when launched from program files. I have also double checked the registry entries and there is no UserChoice sub key for the indd extension and indesign is listed as the first option for the extension.

[image: Registry entry]

There's no errors in the application or the system log that would suggest indesign is malfunctioning. Have tried reinstalling and still not working. Have also tried a number of extension editing programs as well as the built in Default Programs under control panel and still can't get the option to open in indesign.

[image: Control panel extension manager]

I get the same result if trying to change the extention from Set Associations.

Not even sure where to go from here. I'm almost certain it's a problem with indesign and not windows, but can't seem to correct it even after reinstalling. Can't reproduce this with any other program. This computer is virus free and I have tried doing this with my anti virus disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a Repair Installation of InDesign. Normally, among other things, this should re-register any application-specific extensions.

Comment: I'll give that a shot. Adobe forces installations through their application manager so I have to see if repair is even an option.

Comment: Yea, Adobe likes doing things their own way, and I've yet to see how it's better in many cases. As an Admin I find many of their choices frustrating.

Comment: Repair didn't work but fully uninstalling both programs as well as checking the remove preferences box and then using revo to get every last file system and registry entry with a restart between reinstalling ended up working.

Comment: Love me some Revo. :) Glad it worked out for you.